# VBscript values fetched from excel into html inputs being truncated by a space

Tags: html, vbscript

Low level aptitude alert.

Have a form that stores values from html form into an excel sheet which works.

Subsequently need to extracting those values to a similar form but the values are being truncated by spaces in the value.

Code as follows ...

```
report = oWb.sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 11).Value

document.write "<tr><td>Report Title: </td><td><input name=""rpt"" value=" & report & " type=""text"" size=""40"" /></td></tr>"
```

For example a string value stored in excel of "Site Assessment" ... is brought into the form field as "Site"

Any help appreciated.

R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must quote the value of value too:

```
>> report = "Site Assessment"
>> WScript.Echo "input name=""rpt"" value=" & report & " type=""text"""
>> WScript.Echo "input name=""rpt"" value=""" & report & """ type=""text"""
>>
input name="rpt" value=Site Assessment type="text"
input name="rpt" value="Site Assessment" type="text"
```

Comment: Using single quotes in VBS-generated HTML helps avoiding double-quote-hell (e.g. `document.write "<input name='rpt' value='" & report & "' type='text' ... />"`).